# How to ignore special error in RxJava

Tags: rx-java2

I would like to ignore error if it is an instance of for example SpecialError() and not to break the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `retry(Predicate<Throwable>)` to restart the stream for specific throwables, otherwise it will continue the `onError` up the chain.

It is impossible to continue a stream after `onError` has been called however, since the specification defines it as a terminal event.